# How to plot a single point in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'd like to plot a single point on my graph, but it seems like they all need to plot as either a list or equation.

I need to plot like `ax.plot(x, y)` and a dot will be appeared at my `x`, `y` coordinates on my graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import numpy
fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('Width')
plt.ylabel('Height')
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(105, 200)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 121):

This worked for me:

```
plt.plot(105,200,'ro')
```

Comment: r means red, o means dot.

Answer (score 25):

- [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) and [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) plots `y` versus `x` as lines and/or markers.
- `ax.plot(105, 200)` attempts to draw a line, but two points are required for a line

  - `plt.plot([105, 110], [200, 210])`
- A third positional argument consists of line type, color, and/or marker

  - `'o'` can be used to only draw a marker.

    - Specifying `marker='o'` does not work the same as the positional argument.
  - `'ro'` specifies color and marker, respectively
  - `'-o'` or `'-ro'` will draw a line and marker if two or more `x` and `y` values are provided.
- [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) and [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) can also be used to add single or multiple points
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(8, 10), tight_layout=True)

# single point
ax[0].plot(105, 110, '-ro', label='line & marker - no line because only 1 point')
ax[0].plot(200, 210, 'go', label='marker only')  # use this to plot a single point
ax[0].plot(160, 160, label='no marker - default line - not displayed- like OP')
ax[0].set(title='Markers - 1 point')
ax[0].legend()

# two points
ax[1].plot([105, 110], [200, 210], '-ro', label='line & marker')
ax[1].plot([105, 110], [195, 205], 'go', label='marker only')
ax[1].plot([105, 110], [190, 200], label='no marker - default line')
ax[1].set(title='Line & Markers - 2 points')
ax[1].legend()

# scatter plot
ax[2].scatter(x=105, y=110, c='r', label='One Point')  # use this to plot a single point
ax[2].scatter(x=[80, 85, 90], y=[85, 90, 95], c='g', label='Multiple Points')
ax[2].set(title='Single or Multiple Points with using .scatter')
ax[2].legend()
```

[image]

### Seaborn

- [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) is a high-level api for `matplotlib`, and offers additional options for plotting single points.
- [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) and [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) are axes-level plots.

  - `sns.lineplot` has keyword arguments, which are passed to [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html)
  - `sns.scatterplot` has keyword arguments, which are passed to [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html)
- [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) is a figure-level plot, with a `kind=` parameter.

  - `kind='line'` passes to `sns.lineplot`
  - `kind='scatter'` passes to `sns.scatterplot`
- `x=` and `y=` must be passed as a vector in the following cases.

#### axes-level plots

```py
sns.lineplot(x=[1], y=[1], marker='o', markersize=10, color='r')
```

```py
sns.scatterplot(x=[1], y=[1], s=100, color='r')
```

[image]

#### figure-level plots

```py
sns.relplot(kind='line', x=[1], y=[1], marker='o', markersize=10, color='r')
```

```py
sns.relplot(kind='scatter', x=[1], y=[1], s=100, color='r')
```

[image]