# how to graph an acceleration in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was advised to make a graph for the acceleration. As for my computation, I just have a simple computation and have an introduction about the graph in python. When I run the application, I don't see any graph. Why?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def Acf(vf,vi,tf,ti):
    return((vf-vi) / (tf - ti))

print("A = Δv / Δt")
vf = float(input("What is the value of vf? "))
vi = float(input("What is the value of vi? ")) 
tf = float(input("What is the value of tf? "))
ti = float(input("What is the value of ti? "))
print ("A = ", str("("),vf,str("-"),vi,str(")"), str("/"),str("("),tf,str("-"),ti,str(")"))
ans = Acf(vf,vi,tf,ti)
print("A = %0.2f" %ans, "m/s²")
plt.plot(ans)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sidenote: `str("(")` is redundant since `"("` is already `str`.

Comment: What kind of visualization do you expect?

Comment: Another sidenote: You can clean up the prints by better using string formatting like `print(f"A = ({vf} - {vi}) / ({tf} - {ti})")` and `print("A = %0.2f m/s²" % ans)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot a single point in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28504737/7758804)

Answer (score 2):

Acceleration is the slope of a line with time in X and speed in Y. You can plot such line with:

```
plt.plot((ti, tf), (vi, vf), marker='.')
```

Here is a more complete example to give you a matplotlib *quickstart*; assuming 1,2,3,4 for ti,tf,vi,vf:

```
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot((1, 2), (3, 4), marker='.')
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('speed')
ax.set_xlim(xmin=0)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are ploting only one point, the plot function needs an array. Try saving all point in a vector and then calling plot.

Comment: How to do that?