# Line graph does not display values when there is only one value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I try to make a line graph for many CSV files. The problem is when I try to make a graph for csv with only one value. In this situation, graph is just empty.
This is how my code looks like:

```
    rokCzyste = df10Czyste["Rok"].tolist()
    czyste = df10Czyste["Średnia liczba prosiąt urodzonych"].tolist()
    rokInne = df10Inne["Rok"].tolist()
    inne = df10Inne["Średnia liczba prosiąt urodzonych"].tolist()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(rokCzyste,czyste, "-r", label="Czystorasowe")
    ax.plot(rokInne,inne,"-b",label="Inne")
    leg = ax.legend()
    plt.grid(axis="y")
    ax.set_xlabel('Rok')
    ax.set_ylabel('Liczba prosiąt urodzonych')
    plt.title(f"Liczba prosiąt urodzonych czystorasowych i Innych w stadzie {stado}")
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df10['Rok']), max(df10['Rok'])+1))
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.savefig('wykres2.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

This is how graph looks like.
[image: This is how graph looks like]

As you see the graph is empty but he should display one value for each category.
I check DataFrame and it is correct. Datatypes of columns are float or int.

Comment: How do you expect to plot a line with only 1 value? You might want to use `ax.scatter` instead.

Comment: @DavidG When I have only one value it should make a dot.

Comment: `ax.plot(rokCzyste,czyste, ".-r", label="Czystorasowe")` will plot a marker at each data point in addition to the connecting lines. That way you will see a dot if only one data point is available. You might need to play with the options `linewidth` and `markersize` if you want to hide the markers when lines are present.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot a single point in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504737/how-to-plot-a-single-point-in-matplotlib)